# What does an OBJECT EQUALS method do internally? How to know the value stored in an Object eg: Object_Comparison?

Tags: java, string, equals-operator

I know that .equals methods from the Object class in Java compares the content of the object but what does it do in the below code and why is it FALSE as i put in the comment line? Please let me know.

```
public class Object_Comparison {

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Object_Comparison T1 = new Object_Comparison();
    Object_Comparison T2 = new Object_Comparison();
    
    System.out.println("T1-->"+T1);
    System.out.println("T2-->"+T2);
    
    System.out.println("T1-->"+T1.hashCode());
    System.out.println("T2-->"+T2.hashCode());
    
    System.out.println(T1==T2);
    
    System.out.println(T1.equals(T2)); // what does it contain to do and produces the result as false?
}
}
```

O/p:

> T1-->Object_Comparison@1db9742
>
> T2-->Object_Comparison@106d69c
>
> T1-->31168322
>
> T2-->17225372
>
> false
>
> false

Comment: No strings are being compared in your question, and there is no way to know what the `equals()` method call does without seeing the `Object_Comparison` class.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen The class is there, right in front of you.

Comment: If the class doesn't override `equals(Object)` then the result is identical to using `==` (i.e. reference equality). For classes that do override `equals(Object)` you can look at the source code to see how it's implemented; this can be done via your IDE or you can browse the [online repository](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk).

Comment: @GhostCat I believe Robby is pointing out the fact the question _title_ specifically mentions `String` yet the question _body_ doesn't show any use of `String#equals`.

Comment: @Slaw I saw that. But the code in the question itself is clear enough to explain what is going on, imho.

Comment: Unrelated: learn about java naming rules. Variable/field names always go cameCase, and you dont use the "_" character in names, unless for SOME_CONSTANT.

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't use strings, and as your class `Object_Comparison` isn't **overriding** the base `equals()` method from java.lang.Object, therefore expected happens.

Your code creates **two** different object T1 and T2. If you compare the "references" to those objects, they are **different** (T1 != T2). And as the base implementation for `equals()` ... simply does the same check, that method returns false as well.

Given your current code, you could as well replace

```
Object_Comparison T1 = new Object_Comparison();
Object_Comparison T2 = new Object_Comparison();
```

with

```
Object t1 = new Object();
Object t2 ...
```

and get to the exact same results. Because nothing you are showing in your example code does anything different then what you "inherit" from java.lang.Object.

Comment: Without any fields in the class, it is unclear how you want `equals` to behave. What would it compare other than object identity?

Comment: @Thilo Exactly. Thus I am only explaining what is going with that current code. No point in speculating *what else* the OP has on his mind.

Comment: Well, people are not always clear in phrasing their questions. Someone who calls an `equals` method (or any other method) should have an idea what that method is supposed to do. Just trying to get OP to explain what he wanted to happen so that we can better understand what the question is about.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that .equals methods from the Object class in Java compares the content of the object

Not necessarily, no.

Every class has to implement the logic to "compare the content of the object". There is no built-in generic way in Java that works for all classes.

So while it does compare the contents for things like `String` or `ArrayList<Integer>`, that is only because `String`, `ArrayList` and `Integer` have implemented their own versions of the `equals` method accordingly.

If you do not implement `equals` in your own class, you will inherit it from the parent class. And if that ends up being `Object`, then, no, the default implementation provided there does not compare contents: Two objects are only considered equal if they are the same object instance.

And if you do implememt `equals`, make sure to also implement `hashCode()`: [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)